# What are the advantages of using numpy.identity over numpy.eye?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Having looked over the man pages for `numpy`'s [`eye`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) and [`identity`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html), I'd assumed that `identity` was a special case of `eye`, since it has fewer options (e.g. `eye` can fill shifted diagonals, `identity` cannot), but could plausibly run more quickly. However, this isn't the case on either small or large arrays:

```
>>> np.identity(3)                                                  
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.eye(3)                                                       
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> timeit.timeit("import numpy; numpy.identity(3)", number = 10000)
0.05699801445007324
>>> timeit.timeit("import numpy; numpy.eye(3)", number = 10000)     
0.03787708282470703
>>> timeit.timeit("import numpy", number = 10000)                   
0.00960087776184082
>>> timeit.timeit("import numpy; numpy.identity(1000)", number = 10000)
11.379066944122314
>>> timeit.timeit("import numpy; numpy.eye(1000)", number = 10000)     
11.247124910354614
```

What, then, is the advantage of using `identity` over `eye`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`identity` just calls `eye` so there is no difference in how the arrays are constructed. Here's the code for [`identity`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2125):

```
def identity(n, dtype=None):
    from numpy import eye
    return eye(n, dtype=dtype)
```

As you say, the main difference is that with `eye` the diagonal can may be offset, whereas `identity` only fills the main diagonal.

Since the identity matrix is such a common construct in mathematics, it seems the main advantage of using `identity` is for its name alone.

Comment: Do you know why the identity is called eye in many tensor libraries?

Comment: @aeduG: good question - I don't really know. If I had to guess, it's just because the identity matrix is often denoted `I` in mathematical notation, but this letter can't be used in programming languages as it may be confused for the imaginary unit.  `I` and `eye` are homophones, and `eye` is easier to type than `identity`, I suppose.

Comment: Is it common to do an import from within a method?

Answer (score 3):

To see the difference in an example, run the below codes:

```
import numpy as np

#Creates an array of 4 x 4 with the main diagonal of 1

arr1 = np.eye(4)
print(arr1)

print("\n")

#or you can change the diagonal position

arr2 = np.eye(4, k=1)  # or try with another number like k= -2
print(arr2)

print("\n")

#but you can't change the diagonal in identity

arr3 = np.identity(4)
print(arr3)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`np.identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html) returns a **square matrix** (special case of a 2D-array) which is an identity matrix with the main diagonal (i.e. 'k=0') as 1's and the other values as 0's. you can't change the diagonal `k` here.

[`np.eye`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) returns a **2D-array**, which fills the diagonal, i.e. 'k' which can be set, with 1's and rest with 0's.

So, the main advantage depends on the requirement. If you want an identity matrix, you can go for `identity` right away, or can call the `np.eye` leaving the rest to defaults.

But, if you need a 1's and 0's matrix of a particular shape/size or have a control over the diagonal you can go for `eye` method.

Just like how a matrix is a special case of an array, `np.identity` is a special case of `np.eye`.

Additional references:

- [Eye and Identity - HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/np-eye-and-identity/problem)

Comment: How can we generate a multimensional identity array?