# How to create a matrix with zeros and column position equal to row is 1

Tags: python

How can I create an array of any dimension where it's all zeros except for the column position where if it's the same as the row position it's equal to 1. For example, a 4x4 matrix:

```
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Comment: Do you know `numpy.eye`?

Answer (score 1):

That's called an identity matrix in Linear Algebra.
You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.identity(4) # use this
np.eye(4) # or use this
```

As for the difference between them, you can check this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363694/16516114)