# Vectorized merged python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say you have an array x that is 3x3 as follows:

```
>>> xarr
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Similarly a y array as follows:

```
>>> yarr
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Question is: Is there a way to merge (or use in any vectorized way) xarr and yarr in order to get a result array that looks like this:

```
>>> result
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

The idea is to get the result array without using loops and of course without the numpy.diag or numpy.eye etc..

Comment: How would you end up with that result using loops?  That's not a matrix multiply using any normal definition of the term.

Comment: if you initialize result to a 3x3 zeros, a for loop of result[i,i] = 1 can get the result. This is why I mentioned without using loops. Hope this answers your quesiton.

Comment: Well, yes, but in that case `xarr` and `yarr` are not involved at all, so why mention them?  You can generate an identity matrix using `result = np.identity(3)`.

Comment: I think @TimRoberts meant `np.identity(3)`. Alternatively, you can create the identity matrix using `np.eye(3)`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363447/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-numpy-identity-over-numpy-eye) for the difference.

Comment: If you have some hidden agenda, then you need to tell us about it.  The answer to the question "how do I generate this array without using loops?" is to use `np.identity` or `np.eye`.  End of story.

Comment: As others have pointed out, not sure why you want it. Maybe you want to get the diagonal indices from x and y and then using those indices you want to fill a zeros matrix.

Comment: define the merge - with looping code if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
import numpy as np

x =np.array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
y = np.array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
c = np.zeros_like(x)
x = x.nonzero()[1]
y = y.nonzero()[0]

c[x,y] = 1
print(c)
```